# JQuery how to make a smooth transition?

Tags: jquery

Hy,

i have a div with relative position (CSS) and i want to make it to move on the screen, changing the left property.
This should be a smooth transition from (left: 0px;) to (left: 100px;).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) like this:

```
$("#myDiv").animate({ left: '100px' });
```

Do the reverse for the opposite animation, and set the initial left position using CSS like this:

```
#myDiv { left: 0; position: absolute; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourDIV').animate({left:'0px',top:'100px'},1000);
```

where 1000 is your speed